# Spring aop after method not being called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Hello I am trying to update the database using Spring aop's **@After annotation** but the method annotated with `@After` is not being called.

This my SignupController:

```
package com.jpizza.web;

import com.jpizza.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public class SignupController {

    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public String signup(){
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=POST)
    public String formHandler(Customer customer){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

This is my Aspect class:

```
    package com.jpizza.db;

import com.jpizza.model.Customer;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Creed is a worker at jois pizza who registers users
 */
@Aspect
public class Creed implements CustomerDao{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    //This method is not being executed
    @After("execution(* com.jpizza.SignupController.formHandler(..)) && args(customer)")
    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println("About to update data");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO customer (username, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        template.update(sql, customer.getUsername(), customer.getEmail(),customer.getPassword());
    }

}
```

This is my WebConfig.class:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.jpizza.web")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); 
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource source){
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(source);
        jt.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        return jt;
    }

}
```

There ares no errors being logged. I am trying to execute `saveCustomer(Customer)` after `formHandler(Customer)` is executed but it's not working. The page is being redirected `home.jsp` can someone please tell me where I am going wrong??

**Edit:**

I changed my code as suggested but still the @After is not being executed

**WebConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.jpizza.web")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    //added creed as a bean        
    @Bean
   public Creed creed(){
       return new Creed();
   }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); 
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource source){
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(source);
        jt.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        return jt;
    }

}
```

**Creed.java:**

```
    @Aspect
public class Creed implements CustomerDao{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;
    //changed the package name
    @After("execution(* com.jpizza.web.SignupController.formHandler(..)) && args(customer)")
    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println("About to update data");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO customer (username, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        template.update(sql, customer.getUsername(), customer.getEmail(),customer.getPassword());
    }




}
```

Comment: Dont know if its a typo but package name within @After should be com.jpizza.web.SignupController instead of com.jpizza.SignupController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with your configuration:

- Spring does not know anything about your aspect, you have to annotate it with one of Spring's stereotype annotations (e.g. @Component), or define it via @Bean annotation inside your WebConfig class
- There is a typo in your pointcut definition, as pointed out by the first comment :)

Comment: I changed the code like you suggested but still the @After method is not being executed

Comment: I tried an example with your exact pointcut, everything works fine for me. Maybe the aspect is in a different spring-context as the controller? How are you bootstrapping your application?

Comment: it's a web application so it's running on a server

Comment: Your application still needs an "entrypoint", spring needs knows where to start bootstrapping it's context. Normally it's a class extending `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` or a `web.xml` file

Comment: Yes I have a class etending AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer !

Answer (score 0):

The class SignUpController does not implement an interface. Try enabling proxyTargetClass in the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```